# String Interpolation Resulting in Undefined Error in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I am trying to display some data to the view in my Angular 2 app via string interpolation. For most of the page that's working, but I'm getting an error in this one section that's not making sense to me. It looks like it should work, but I'm getting an 'undefined' error.

Here's what the data looks like that I'm accessing (note: "contacts" is on the root of the document):

```
"contacts": [
    {
        "contact": {
            "_id": "111111111",
            "email": [
                "person@email.com"
            ],
            "name": {
                 "first": "Person",
                 "last": "Lastname"
            }
     }
]
```

I am trying to access the email value in my template using this:

First I tried accessing the email address like this:

```
{{contacts[0]?.contact?.email[0]}}
```

But got this error:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

So then I tried a named index:

```
{{contacts['contact']?.email[0]}}
```

This is also not working. I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'contact' of undefined

And this is for a record where I know there is a value there. So I'm unclear why this isn't working? Anything look wrong about how I'm accessing the values here?

Comment: seeing that your "data" is an object with a property `contacts`, of course contacts[0] wouldn't work. `contacts` is a property of an object. You're not showing all of your code. you would need something like: `objectName.contacts[0]....`

Comment: It should work in the context. You're making assumptions about what the code looks like. No, I'm not showing all the code, but you shouldn't assume you know what it looks like and declare that "of course" something wouldn't work.

Comment: When you don't show a `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`, all we can do is make assumptions. And, it's not an assumption. The structure of the code you showed is NOT how an variable is declared.

Comment: It is an assumption. And I understand if you find it difficult to answer without full context, but sometimes that's not feasible. Still an assumption though. Either way, have figured out the issue and am moving on.

Comment: It is not an assumption. The code you showed shows how an object is DEFINED, not DECLARED. But whatever. Good luck with that.

Comment: `contacts` is an array, YES. `contacts` ITSELF is a PROPERTY of an overlying OBJECT. If you said `contacts = [...]`, than YES its an array and thats IT. But your code shows `"contacts": [...]`, which is how you DEFINE an OBJECT or PROPERTY. AND ESPECIALLY since there are quotes around `"contacts"`, that MUST mean its an PROPERTY.

Comment: @Ademo could you please post your answer if you have figured out the issue so that its helpful for future references?

Answer (score 0):

**`Contacts`** is an **`array`**, you should access with **`index`**

```
{{contacts[0]?.contact?.email[0]}}
```

if not use **`ngFor`**

```
<li *ngFor="let conctact of contacts">
      {{ conctact.email[0]}}
</li>
```

Comment: I tried that first, and still get an error:
Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: how do you assign contacts?

Comment: it is relevant, show the code in ts where you assign contacts

Comment: this.contacts = ? , this is called assign

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155620/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ademo).

Comment: Seems he gets data from server so `contacts` is `undefined`